# How to create and control seperate Java Execution from a Java execution

Tags: java

I have started a Java program, when it is running I wanted to start another Java execution (Separate java.exe execution) for which .class file and supportive JAR files should be finalized by the currently running program.

For Example; if I run A.class, I want A class to start new Java execution using B class and A class should pass all supported JAR files (creating execution environment). B class should run as separate Java execution and A class should be able to stop the B class execution.

How to achieve this.

Comment: have you ever heard of multithreading?

Comment: How I wanted to use is, if I start two separate execution (Say class B and C), static variable and methods of one execution should not be shared with another. If I use thread to start two separate execution, one thread can access static variable and method of another thread right. I am trying to give downward compatibility, in all my class files, static members are declared as public.

Comment: This just sounds like an xy/design (and perhaps, lack of foreknowledge) problem. Lose the static (and keeping them as public fields), and try to work on your foundation for OOP concepts. Good place to start is [Oracle's tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html)